# Sorting words with html elements using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Sorting doesn't work for this code

```js
var element='<p><strike>Mango</strike></p>/n<p><em>Orange</em></p>/n<h1>Apple</h1>/n<p><strong>banana</strong></p>/n<p>grape</p>';

var value=element.split("/n").sort();
var html='';
for(var i=0;i<value.length;i++){
      
      html+=value[i]+'<br>';
}
document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = html;
```

```html
<div id="output"></div>
```

but i need a sorted answer like this

## Apple

**banana**

grape

<strike>Mango</strike>

*Orange*

Comment: Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before attempting to ask more questions. What you have done is not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to sort on just the text contents of each item, which is easy to do with jQuery because if you pass your html string to the `$()` function you get back a jQuery object containing a list of the top-level elements (so the paragraphs and the h1), and then you can sort that based on each one's `.text()`. (Noting that [the `.text()` method](http://api.jquery.com/text/) gets text even from nested elements.)

Also you should remove the `'/n'` from the string or those characters will end up on the page. (Did you intend for those to be newline characters? If so, it should be `'\n'`, not `'/n'`.)

```js
var element='<p><strike>Mango</strike></p>/n<p><em>Orange</em></p>/n<h1>Apple</h1>/n<p><strong>banana</strong></p>/n<p>grape</p>';

// remove the '/n's
element = element.replace(/>\/n/g, '>');

var value = $(element);
value.sort(function(a, b) {
  return $(a).text().localeCompare($(b).text());
});

$("#output").append(value);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="output"></div>
```

Comment: it's not working for the digits `<p>50</p><p>40</p><p>30</p><p>10</p><p>99</p><p>10000</p>`

Comment: Yes, I showed a text-based sort because that worked for the data that was in your question. If you want to sort numeric data you need to change the sort function to `return $(a).text() - $(b).text()`.

Comment: for my question. how can i do it for descending order?

Comment: `return $(b).text().localeCompare($(a).text());` for descending order